# How can PHP see client side cookies?

Tags: php, cookies

How can PHP see client side cookies?

To elaborate:
When working with PHP & Javascript, I understand that PHP gets processed on the server side. While Javascript happens on the client side.

In Javascript I can check and set these client cookies. That makes sense.

However, with PHP, if I check a client cookie value as part of a conditional statement that also sets , how is PHP able to see the clients cookie value while the PHP is happening on the server side?

Here's an example of the PHP conditional that lives in a php file:

```
<?PHP
if ($_COOKIE["name"] == “Mickey”) {
    setcookie(“fulsome”, “Mickey Mouse”, time()+3600);  
}
?>
```

Comment: Cookies are included in every requests header

Comment: When browser sends the request to the server it also sent the cookies with request read the HTTP tutorials for more understanding

Comment: You have curly quotes `‘ ’` and `“ ”` - If those are your actual quotes, your code will fail and cause a 500 error.

Comment: Here's a scenario: I go to test.com. I went there last week and have the cookie named "name". I call www.test.com/index.php . Can someone explain how PHP aoutomatically is able to see this cookie sitting on the clients browser/computer?

Comment: "Cookies are included in every requests header": That's the answer I was looking for. So I assume the setCookie part get's implemented when it's set back to the client.

Answer (score 7):

There is no such thing as a client side cookie.

A cookie is a piece of data associated with a set of URLs in a browser. Every time the browser makes an HTTP request to one of those URLs, the cookie is included in the Request headers.

They were originally designed to be set via HTTP Response headers.

An API was added to browsers that allows them to be created and set by JavaScript. These are still regular cookies though and will be included in every request to the associated URLs.

It is possible to mark a cookie as `http_only` which will cause browsers to prevent access to that cookie from JavaScript. There is no direct equivalent for imposing a similar limit going the other way. The closest you could come to that would be to use something like Local Storage instead of cookies.

Answer (score 2):

> how is PHP able to see the clients cookie value while the PHP is
>   happening on the server side?

The reason is that **each request to server also bring cookies in headers** like i have inspected in chorome network tab, my php website and got this:

[image]

Cookies are store on client side but are accessible on server side through **request header**. As @Quentin stated in his answer *"Every time the browser makes an HTTP request to one of those URLs, the cookie is included in the Request headers."*

Comment: Neat: may I ask where you're viewing that header data in? I mostly use Chrome or Firefox's developer tools.

Comment: Yes i have mentioned in the answer "chrome network tab"

Answer (score 0):

(Based on the comments, I wanted to leave a full answer as I understand it).

HTTP headers include existing cookies for the domain/site.

When PHP checks a cookie, the cookie & it's value got there via the HTTP Header that was sent in the call to the php file.

When PHP sets a cookie, it will be sent with the HTTP Header going back to the client, where it will then be set up on the client.

For a full list of what is sent in the Header, and the response back Header, see this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

You'll see Cookie in the Header Field List, and Set-Cookie in the list of response fields.